# Android service is instantiated again on second call to bindService()

Tags: android, android-service

I have a `Service` that I want to start when my app launches, and later bind to it from different activities to give it some commands to run in a worker thread. I can start the service fine, and the **first** time I bind to it in an activity using `bindService`, it attaches to the instance created when I originally invoked `startService`.

However, the **second** time I call `bindService`, a *new* instance is created! According to my understanding of the docs, this shouldn't be happening -- since I started the service manually with `startService` it should act like a singleton, and any subsequent calls to bind to it should act on the same service.

I added Logcat calls to the constructor, `onStartCommand`, and `onDestroy` calls. The first service is never destroyed, yet the constructor and start command are called again on this second bind:

```
Starting service from app launch...
Service instantiated
onStartCommand called
binding from Activity A
calling method A from binder
binding from Activity B
Service instantiated
onStartCommand called
calling method B from binder
```

Comment: Can you show some code please

Comment: there is one instance: add Log.d in onCreate and in onDestroy and you will see that

Comment: @pskink The Logcat calls are in the question text. There are definitely two instances, since `Service instantiated` is in the constructor of my `Service` class.

Comment: try to log hashCode()

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added more logging to method A in the service binder, and discovered it was not returning. I commented out the method body so that it returned immediately, which caused method B to be properly called on the same service instance. I assume that since method A was being called in the `onServiceConnected` callback on the main thread, that this impacted how the future bind call was performed somehow.

tl;dr -- issues with my particular `Binder` implementation and not having a started and bound service.